# Returning multiple case statements on one row in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm using the following T-SQL statement to return some values:

```
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 1 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS January,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 2 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS Febuary,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 3 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS March,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 4 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS April,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 5 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS May,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 6 THEN m.pcp_valuen ELSE NULL END AS June,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 7 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS July,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 8 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS August,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 9 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS September,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 10 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS October,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 11 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS November,
CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 12 THEN m.pcp_value ELSE NULL END AS December
```

However this is returning all of these values on different rows

```
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
208333.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Is there any way to make them appear on the same row? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, what you have is a `CASE` expression, not a `Case` (`Switch`) statement. The 2 are quite different and the latter is not found in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want aggregation:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 1 THEN m.pcp_value END) AS January,
MAX(CASE WHEN month(m.pcp_startdate) = 2 THEN m.pcp_value END) AS February,
```

You may have to adjust the `GROUP BY` in your query as well, but you don't show that in your question.

Comment: Thank you, have removed both of the fields in the CASE from the group by and it's worked!

Answer (score 0):

looks like a pivot table to me?

```sql
SELECT
    'amountOutstanding' as [val], [1] as Jan, [2] as Feb, [3] as Mar, [4] as Apr, [5] as May, [6] as Jun, [7] as Jul, [8] as Aug, [9] as Sep, [10] as Oct, [11] as Nov, [12] as Dec
FROM 
( select [amount], [month] from m) as a
PIVOT
(
avg([amount])
FOR [month] in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) as pt;
```